# Change color of ToggleID link

Tags: javascript, toggle

A site I am contributing to does not allow adding of pages for a navigation. Therefore, in order to have a nav-like functionality with corresponding information, I thought it would be best to go with a toggle nav using Javascript. As I'm new to javascript, I have gotten as far as getting the toggle working. How do I highlight the nav link that is selected? Secondly, how can I have the selected nav link onload be highlighted?

```
<script>
    function toggleID(IDS) {
        var area = document.getElementById('content');
        var sel = area.getElementsByTagName('div');
        for (var i=0; i<sel.length; i++) { sel[i].style.display = 'none'; }
        if (IDS == '') { return; }
        document.getElementById(IDS).style.display = 'block';    
    }
    onload = function() {
        toggleID('level1');
    }
</script>

<body>
    <ul id="nav-vertical">
        <li onclick="toggleID('level1')">level 1</li>
        <li onclick="toggleID('level2')">level 2</li>
    </ul><!-- /.nav-vertical -->
    <div id="content">
    <div id="level1">
      <p>this is content for level1.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="level2">
      <p>this is content for level2.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What is not working...? and you don't have `content` nor any `<div>`  in your HTML nor changing colors in your script!. **Trolling?**

Comment: Wow! "Browsed through all of StackOverflow"! How long did that take? There are more than 220 thousand JavaScript questions alone!

Comment: Hey gdoron, I'm very new to javascript and have been trying to figure out how to style the link when the toggle is open. Though I figured out how to open/close the toggle, I haven't figured out how to add the color to the link when it is open. I didn't add the "content" or "divs" as I didn't think it was relevant for this question. I posted this question because I don't know how to change the colors. I am not a troll just a newbie. ;)  Ken, I've been looking for several days before deciding to post - I assure you, I looked through more than you would believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the color change, you can modify your function `toggleID`:

```
<script>
    function toggleID(IDS, clickedObject) {

        // toggle the color of the clickedObject too
        if ( clickedObject && clickedObject.style.backgroundColor == 'red' ) {
            clickedObject.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
        }
        else if ( clickedObject ) {
            clickedObject.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        }

        var area = document.getElementById('content');
        var sel = area.getElementsByTagName('div');
        for (var i=0; i<sel.length; i++) { sel[i].style.display = 'none'; }
        if (IDS == '') { return; }
        document.getElementById(IDS).style.display = 'block';    
    }
    onload = function() {
        toggleID('level1');
    }
</script>

<body>
    <ul id="nav-vertical">
        <li onclick="toggleID('level1', this)">level 1</li>
        <li onclick="toggleID('level2', this)">level 2</li>
    </ul><!-- /.nav-vertical -->
</body>
```

You can provide the clicked link as a second parameter to your function and toggle its background color property in the function.